# How do I get the base elements from an array or a list?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a list with 500 repeating names:

[name1, name2, name1, name7,name2,name1, name1, name1, name134, name11, etc...]

I want to create a list with only the base names for example if there are only N base names then the list should be:

[name1, name2, name3, name4, ... , name(N)]

how would I do this the fast and easy way?

Comment: Are you saying you want to get rid of repeating names? Assuming your list is stored in `names`, you can do `set(names)` to get unique names.

Comment: Could you provide code that illustrates how you tried to solve this problem - that way  it is easier for people to provide useful and timely answers.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by base names?
To get a list of unique names, you can just do:

```
list(set(names))
```

This converts the initial `list` to a `set`, and you're again converting the `set` to a `list`

Comment: Thanks all for the quick responses. The set(list) code is what I was looking for.

Comment: How do I make this set with index reference? I am trying to access a certain index but it gives me this error "TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing"

Comment: Like I said, type cast the set into a list. So you can do the following:
```yourList = list(set(name))``` 
and then access the index you want:
```yourList[5]```

Comment: Also, could you please accept this as the answer if it answers your query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
list_of_repeating_names = [name1, name2, name1, name7,name2,name1, name1, name1, name134, name11, ]
sorted_unique_names = sorted(list(set(list_of_repeating_names)))
```

returns

```
['name1', 'name11', 'name134', 'name2', 'name7']
```

The `set` deletes the duplicates but is unordered, you convert it into a list that you sort.

Answer (score 0):

With **set**()  you can have an unordered collections of **unique** elements:

```
myList = ['name1', 'name2', 'name1', 'name7', 'name2', 'name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name134', 'name11']
mySet = set(myList)
print(mySet)
```

{'name134', 'name11', 'name2', 'name1', 'name7'}

The **list**() constructor returns a mutable sequence list of elements:

```
myNewList = list(mySet)
print(myNewList)
```

['name134', 'name11', 'name2', 'name1', 'name7']

**sorted**() returns a new sorted list:

```
myNewSortedList = sorted(myNewList)
print(myNewSortedList)
```

['name1', 'name11', 'name134', 'name2', 'name7']

Comment: Thanks, I am new to python and the set(list) is the code i was looking for.